# Rund Docker with options from Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, mqtt

I can run docker image with option `-c` with command:

```
docker run -it -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 eclipse-mosquitto mosquitto -c /mosquitto-no-auth.conf
```

It runs fine, but how to run image with option `-c` from `Docker Desktop` ?